# gem update 時に対話入力をスキップする方法

Tags: rubygems, fluentd

サーバー内の初期設定をレシピ化したいと思っています

その中で fluentd の使うジェムをアップデートするため

```
/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem update --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

を実行した際

```
rdoc's executable "ri" conflicts with /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ri
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

という対話インターフェースが出て実行が止まってしまいます

fluent-gem 自体は fluentd が使うジェムを別に管理するために別名になっているだけで
gem コマンドと同じだと思うのですが対話インターフェースをスキップする方法
あるいは rdoc ri の conflict の解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか

よろしくおねがいします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinuxライクなOSであれば、`yes`コマンドを使う方法があります。

```
$ yes | fluent-gem update --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

`yes`コマンドは実行すると`y`と標準出力に表示し続けるので、パイプで任意のコマンドの入力として渡せばすべてに`y(yes)`と答えたことになります。

参考:
[How to default the [Yn] responses for the Ruby “gem clean” command? - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022669/2322778) の回答